# Detect if "enable system diagnostics" is checked for conditionals in pipeline file and scripts

Tags: azure-devops

I need to use the "enable system diagnostics" checkbox state in the pipeline run UI.   How do I check if it was checked?  For both pipeline YAML file and in a bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Detect if “enable system diagnostics” is checked for conditionals in pipeline file and scripts

The answer is yes.

If we enable the checkbox "enable system diagnostics" in the pipeline run UI, we could get following info in the build log:

```
agent.diagnostic : true
```

[image]

So, we could use this variable for conditionals in pipeline file and scripts.

But, there is a little different from the Boolean variables we usually use. If we do not enable the checkbox `enable system diagnostics`, Azure devops will not create this variable to overwrite the variable `system.debug`. So this variable does not exist at this time, we cannot directly determine whether its value is `true` or `false`. We could  judge whether this value exists to judge its result.

Below is my test `bash` scripts for this condition:

```
- bash: |
   if [ -z "$(agent.diagnostic)" ]
   then
         echo "enable system diagnostics is Unchecked"
   else
         echo "enable system diagnostics is Checked"
   fi
  displayName: 'enable system diagnostics'
```

Comment: What is the difference between system.debug and agent.diagnostic.  Both turn to true when I check diagnostic.

Comment: @jhurtas, `agent.diagnostic` is an overwrite of `system.debug`, so that we can directly set whether to enable detailed logging by checking the checkbox `enable system diagnostics` when queueing pipeline directly, instead of editing the pipeline every time to modify the variable `system.debug`. If you set `system.debug` to `false`, and enable checkbox `enable system diagnostics`， it will overwrite the `system.debug`  to `true`. That is reason why you see `Both turn to true when I check diagnostic`.

Answer (score -1):

This is equivalent to the `System.Debug` variable. As an environment variable, `SYSTEM_DEBUG`.

Comment: $(System.Debug) worked, but not $SYSTEM_DEBUG